# Example of Serial Upvoting?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Yesterday (2016-01-07), I received at least 14 upvotes within 10 minutes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=reputation)).  Although appreciative of upvotes and confident in my deserving them (;-), this does seem like an example of serial upvoting.

When this has happened in the past, the votes have been reversed on the same day.  However, they have not been reversed . . . which is why I am pointing this out.

I should note that reversing the upvotes should not actually affect my reputation (due to other upvotes).  However, the serial detection algorithm should still be detecting them.

Comment: The script runs daily at 03:00 UTC (in about 14 minutes).

Comment: *Write an SQL query to detect them!* :)

Comment: I just received some serial upvotes as well. Someone is probably serial upvoting people on the top users page... you're currently in first like usual, and I'm in second for the month...

Comment: Why would anyone do this, though? Hat hunting? Or do users beyond 100k get their own fan club who love everything they write no matter what it is? :)

Comment: @Lundin Some people upvote tons of questions for the Gold Badge,

Comment: On topic: How do you even post that much you content generating machine :O

Comment: @Magisch Aah. Hat hunting, badge hunting... a rose by any other name. The electorate badge, yes? I didn't even know such a badge existed, even though I apparently have gotten it myself :)

Comment: @Lundin Yes, the one that wants you to upvote 600 Questions. Some people go crazy about that kind of stuff (Its the only golden one I got on the main site, too! On here I don't even have it, just one reversal (I missed another one by 1 upvote, too) :(

Comment: @Lundin It doesn't need to be for malice or system gaming purposes.  If you browse highly voted answers from high rep users, you'll generally see a lot of awesome material.  If you don't know that it's frowned on and will likely be blown away by a script, going down the list and thinking "that's really good, +1" to most of what you're reading is a natural action.

Comment: @DanNeely Yeah of course, but the key here is the time frame. Can you really read, understand & judge 14 posts in 10 minutes?

Comment: Were those 14 votes made by the same user? I can probably go through 2-3 posts in that time, depending on their length of course, so 5 users doing that would be enough.

Comment: @Lundin Reading Gordon's top 5 answers and the associated questions took me 4 minutes; so doing 14 in 10 doesn't strike me as implausible.  I didn't read any comments or other answers; but there're about eleventy jillion posts on meta about problems related to a bad accepted answer because so many people don't look at anything else; so I don't see anything wrong with making that assumption for my test either.

Comment: I pity the fool that wants to spend their time up-voting 600 questions they haven't read just for the hollow victory of earning a gold badge. Is anyone really that sad?

Comment: Reading this post makes me feel like randomly upvoting a few dozen of Gordon's top answers.

Comment: @BenThurley It probably makes them happy, actually. That's why people tend to badge hunt; they like having them.

Comment: @BenThurley Instead, upvote the newest questions. They're probably not by the same user!

Comment: By voting lots, you get your name on the [Voters](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters) tab in [Users](http://stackoverflow.com/users) too.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 our newbie badge hunters are probably afraid that they'll get caught out for upvoting crap if they just vote down the front page (are there any checks for this sort of behavior?).  Upvoting stuff that lots of other people have upvoted before seems to be a safer move (but isn't).

Comment: I noticed that Gordon's rep did not meet its usual 300 point per day on Christmas and New Year's.  What a slacker!

Comment: I was serial upvoted a little over a year ago. It was sometime the next month before the votes were corrected.

Comment: There are genuine cases where serial upvoting is valid, IMHO - from time to time I'll stumble across a user who has contributed a lot of useful questions/answers on am obscure subject that I'm interested in and I'll go back through these and maybe upvote 5 or 10 in the process - is this a Bad Thing to do ?

Comment: I've been on SO for a few weeks and there was a day that I searched for the best posts on topics that are very important to me: Vagrant, Packer, Solr, Puppet, etc. I was curious about the quality of questions and how comprehensive and well-researched the answers were. I was **really** impressed and used up my 40 votes that day, but I actually read the answers in their entirety as well as the comments on them. I got a couple badges for it, but that wasn't what I was after. The 40 vote daily limit is a good policy as well as a reasonable throttle on the speed of voting. Gamers gonna game.

Comment: So how did the story end? Were those upvotes reverted?